# JSONArray to String in java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, string

I have an `JSONArray` that looks  like this:

[image]

how can i convert that to a string?

if i try:

```
json.toString();
```

the string is:

```
["package.package.ChecklistModels.ChecklistAnswer@405dddd8","package.package.ChecklistModels.ChecklistAnswer@405ddf48","package.package.ChecklistModels.ChecklistAnswer@405de070","package.package.ChecklistModels.ChecklistAnswer@405de198","package.package.ChecklistModels.ChecklistAnswer@405de2c0","package.package.ChecklistModels.ChecklistAnswer@405de3e8","package.package.ChecklistModels.ChecklistAnswer@405de510"]
```

but i want something like this:

```
    {
 "json": 
    "values": [
        {
            "answer": "true",
            "remark":"",
            "questionId": "0"
            "checklistId": "2"
        },
        {
            "answer": "true",
            "remark":"",
            "questionId": "0"
            "checklistId": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT:

this a snipped how i make the json array:

```
   if(cb.isChecked() || !text.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    ChecklistAnswer answer = new ChecklistAnswer(questions.get(id).id, 2, cb.isChecked(), text.getText().toString());

                    answers.add(answer);
                }
            }
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(answers);
            String jsonString = json.toString();
```

Comment: it works as intended ... you just put `ChecklistAnswer` object into array ... not `JSONObject` ... `ChecklistAnswer.toString()` returns "xx.xx.xx.ChecklistAnswer@XXX" ... so either override ChecklistAnswer.toString method to return json string or make a function to translate ChecklistAnswer to JSOObject

Comment: show codes used for json parsing

Comment: i added some code @CapDroid

Comment: @Rikkert09 did you got answer ?

Comment: that function doesnt exist... @CapDroid

Comment: OMG do not try this(do not waste your time - CapDroid is [by-try programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation)) ... take a look at my prev comment

Comment: that doesnt work CapDroid, @Selvin i dont understand what you mean there can you make an example or explain it to me?

Comment: instead `answers.add(answer);` use `answers.add(answer.toJSONObject());` (and yeah, you have to write `toJSONObject` method inside  `ChecklistAnswer` by yourself - which should be pretty simple - like putting all ChecklistAnswer`s properties into new JSONObject)

Comment: Ok, im gonna try that @Selvin

Comment: Cool that wasn't so hard after all :D Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the JSONArray.toString(), as @Selvin mentioned.

From JSONArray source:

```
/**
 * Encodes this array as a compact JSON string, such as:
 * <pre>[94043,90210]</pre>
 */
@Override public String toString() {
    try {
        JSONStringer stringer = new JSONStringer();
        writeTo(stringer);
        return stringer.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Encodes this array as a human readable JSON string for debugging, such
 * as:
 * <pre>
 * [
 *     94043,
 *     90210
 * ]</pre>
 *
 * @param indentSpaces the number of spaces to indent for each level of
 *     nesting.
 */
public String toString(int indentSpaces) throws JSONException {
    JSONStringer stringer = new JSONStringer(indentSpaces);
    writeTo(stringer);
    return stringer.toString();
}
```

The problem is that you need to convert your ChecklistAnswer to JSON object first for your JSONArray to work properly.

Again from Javadoc:

```
/**
 * A dense indexed sequence of values. Values may be any mix of
 * {@link JSONObject JSONObjects}, other {@link JSONArray JSONArrays}, Strings,
 * Booleans, Integers, Longs, Doubles, {@code null} or {@link JSONObject#NULL}.
 * Values may not be {@link Double#isNaN() NaNs}, {@link Double#isInfinite()
 * infinities}, or of any type not listed here.
```

...

Answer (score 1):

In my ChecklistAnwer class i added:

```
   public JSONObject toJsonObject(){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("questionId", questionId);
        json.put("checklistId", checklistId);
        json.put("answer", answer);
        json.put("remark", remark);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}
```

and in my other class:

```
JSONArray answers = new JSONArray();

ChecklistAnswer answer = new ChecklistAnswer(questions.get(id).id, 2, cb.isChecked(),         text.getText().toString());

answers.put(answer.toJsonObject());
```

if i filled the array:

```
String js = answers.toString(1);
```

and that returns:

```
[
 {
  "answer": true,
  "questionId": 1,
  "remark": "",
  "checklistId": 2
 },
 {
  "answer": false,
  "questionId": 4,
  "remark": "teesxfgtfghyfj",
  "checklistId": 2
 },
 {
  "answer": true,
  "questionId": 4,
  "remark": "",
  "checklistId": 2
 },
 {
  "answer": true,
  "questionId": 4,
  "remark": "",
  "checklistId": 2
 },
 {
  "answer": true,
  "questionId": 4,
  "remark": "",
  "checklistId": 2
 },
 {
  "answer": true,
  "questionId": 4,
  "remark": "",
  "checklistId": 2
 },
 {
  "answer": true,
  "questionId": 4,
  "remark": "",
  "checklistId": 2
 }
]
```

thanks to @Selvin

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any extra libraries. The `JSONArray` class has [an extra `.toString(int)` method](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#toString%28int%29) that does the pretty printing for you. The `int` parameter is the indentation factor.

```
JSONArray arr = ...
System.out.println(arr.toString(4));
```

It also works with a `JSONObject`.

Your bigger problem is that your `JSONArray` is not being constructed properly. You're supposed to add other `JSONArray`s and `JSONObject`s to it, but you're adding other objects. They are implicitly being turned into `String`s. You need to convert them to JSON before putting them into your array.

Comment: sorry but problem is not here ...  JSONArray.toString(int) == JSONArray.toString() with default values (prolly without formating at all)

Comment: @Selvin Looks like he had two problems! In any case, I've now covered both.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that there is only one problem ... the formatting problem doesn't exists (he doesn't need formatted json - the formatted json is better for question's readability)

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me

```
String result = json.toString(4);
```

I was trying to write it into the file and this is perfect.

Answer (score -1):

You can use gson library : https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String output = gson.toJson(object);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
JsonArray jArray = //Your Json Array;
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
jObj.put("test", jArray);
String requiredString = jObj.optString("test");
```