# How to change into the string from json array which holds the json object? (JAVA)

Tags: java, json

I have a json file which is

```
 [
  {
   "time" : "72",
  "min" : "22"
 }
]
```

So, in order me to change into the java, I used

```
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
 JSONObject json = new JSONobject();
 json.put("time","72");
 json.put("min","22");
 array.put(json);
```

Now I am not sure how I can change into the string that array which has an json object?
Like can I save it into the string variable in java?

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776200/jsonarray-to-string-in-java) the code you're looking for?

```
String jsonString = json.toString();
```